# Adjusting form size based on usercontrols

Tags: html, asp.net, web, user-controls

I have a web form hosting 10 different user controls(inside panels in form). I need to adjust the form size based on user controls. Only one user control will be visible at a time .

How to resize the form

Comment: The form should resize automatically. Don't give it a fixed height/width. Use `width:auto;height:auto`

Comment: Code please. What have you tried. Details...

Comment: I was trying to register the script to resize the form in user control. Didn't work . Found a workaround to pass the dialog height since the form is opened from another form